# Using the select_related function in Django

Tags: python, django

Hi so i'm trying to display table retailer_book, but instead of a seller_id, i want it to display the retailer instead. These are the tables

```
class retailer(models.Model):
    sellerID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    retailer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.retailer


class retailer_book(models.Model):
    ISBN = models.ForeignKey(books, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    sellerID = models.ForeignKey(retailer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    reviews= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ID =  models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bookType = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I've tried :

```
object_list1 = retailer_book.objects.filter(ISBN_id = query).select_related("sellerID_id")
```

but it doesn't display retailer when i try to display it.

Here's my views.py

```
class SearchResultsView1(ListView):
    model = books
    template_name = 'TextSearch/search_results.html'
    context_object_name = "object_list"

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list1 = retailer_book.objects.filter(ISBN_id = query).select_related("sellerID_id")
        return object_list
```

and here's my HTML code

```
<h1>Book Options: </h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Retailer </th>
        <th> condition </th>
        <th> Book Type </th>
        <th> Reviews </th>
        <th> Price </th>
    </tr>
    {% for result in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>
          {{result.ID}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{result.retailer}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{result.condition}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{result.bookType}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{result.reviews}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{result.price}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your `ForeignKey` from `retailer_book` to `retailer` is `sellerID` but you are referencing the related object in your HTML template as `retailer`. Try either of these two:

1. rename your `ForeignKey` field to `retailer` (recommended),
2. rename your reference to retailer within your HTML template           `{{result.retailer}} -> {{result.sellerID}}`

Comment: I'm referencing it cause I want it to print retailer instead of sellerID

Comment: Then the latter will work for you. Please consider that retailer is a field of retailer_book and is accessible only via sellerID like result.sellerID.retailer. Or if you wish you can only use result.sellerID which will be printing retailer field as defined in its __str__